# Why am I getting multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by
>   multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

When this runs:

```
public bool AddUser(string username, string clanName) {

            if (userRankValid(clanName))
            {
                var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
                ApplicationUser recruit = userManager.FindByNameAsync(username).Result;
                Clan clan = uow.ClansRepository.Get(u => u.Name == clanName).FirstOrDefault();

                if (clan != null && recruit != null)
                {
                    var ctum = uow.ClanToUserRepository.Get(u => u.User.UserName == username).Where(u=>u.Clan.Name == clanName).FirstOrDefault();
                    if(ctum == null)
                    {
                        ClanToUserMap recMap = new ClanToUserMap();
                        recMap.Clan = clan;
                        recMap.User = recruit;
                        recMap.Rank = "Private";
                        recMap.User = recruit;
                       //clan.Members.Add(recMap);
                      //  recruit.Clans.Add(recMap);
                        uow.ClanToUserRepository.Insert(recMap);
                        uow.Save();
                        return true;
                    } 
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Now then, I realise this must be because there are multiple instances of a context. What I don't understand is why there are... All the calls are get and then a final insert. But I am implementing .AsNoTracking() in my generic repository for any GET call, so I don't understand why the contexts are getting confused:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter).AsNoTracking();
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty).AsNoTracking();
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).AsNoTracking().ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.AsNoTracking().ToList();
            }
        }
```

The error occurs on the INSERT

Comment: Does the "FindByNameAsync" use AsNoTracking - given the recruit is fetched using this and is then effectively referenced by a change tracker when the Insert is performed...

Comment: Where is `uow` defined?

Comment: No worries @user2330270